# How to bind the values which are in response (debugging) to the textboxt using jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to get the City name related to the key type in the text box.

I have written the below code to get the city name and other further related details from geo complete, Whenever I am entering any key in the text box i am not getting anything, But if I will check in Network/Response using debugging its showing the city names as per the entered key in the text box.

```
My .html file
<input type="text" id="txt_Address" />

<script src="../../../../lib/geoexample.js"></script> //file for api
<script src="/Communications/Edit.js"></script> 
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            _file.loadJs("/Communications/Edit.js", function () {
                _Communication.initial();
            });
        });
    </script>

My .js file

var _Communication = {
    initial: function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('txt_Address');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
},
}
```

Whenever user type any key in the textbox the citynames related to that entered key should come,  This is nothing but a geocomplete, but I am getting data in response of debugging in browser... How to get the result in textbox.

Comment: Your js file declares `__Communication` with two underscores in front, but the call in your HTML file uses `_Communication` with one underscore... You likely have some errors in your console about that...

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's not the problem, I just changed the name earlier it was too long to avoid the confusion i changed it to as simple as. I am using the same name in both the files. Please give a suggestion where it may be wrong.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the real code, and perhaps you'll get better suggestions...

Comment: @HereticMonkey made changes... or edited the Question.

Comment: Well, you're calling `initial` once, and passing an `HTMLInputElement` to `Autocomplete`. I don't know anything about the Google Maps stuff, so I can't say if that's how it's supposed to work. I took the liberty of adding a tag for that so that experts may see this questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no problem man, Actually now I am getting the response values in textbox, but not getting as per the requirements(if u see any video of geocomplete autocomplete city there will be a Google Logo in bottom of that dropdown list.), In current case If i enter Cal in textbox then again i have to press the down arrow key then only the name California will come in the textbox. By the way Thank You.